# Why Visual states do not work?

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to create animatable control but it seems animation does not works. What happened with VisualStateManager ?

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="loginStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="ready">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="loginControls" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0000000">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="done">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="loginControls" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0000000">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <StackPanel x:Name="loginControls">
    <TextBlock Text="some text" /> 
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: I've found that this code works fine against the Page, but does not work against ChildWindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, the only way for ChildWindow is to use StoryBoard:

```
ready.StoryBoard.Begin();
```

Comment: You're right ... apparently Visual States don't work in a Child Window.  Yet another XAML gotcha :(